# How to get AWS CloudFront Data Consumption from Edge Server to Clients based on a Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I want to generate reports of Data being transferred over the Cloudfront CDN based on the S3 Keys for a particular date range. Cloudfront Points to a S3 bucket as a source which contains all the static objects.